# Deleting a row from database in PHP

Tags: php, database

I want to delete a row from MySQL database but I'm not able to do this although I can update the row .
The first part is updating code, the second part is deleting code.

The funny thing is that it shows me the alert of successfully deleted but actually in MySQL database nothing is going to change.

```
<?php
// for updating Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit'] == 'update')
  {
$sql1=mysql_query(" UPDATE `".$tbl_name."` SET  `username`='".$_REQUEST['user']."' , `password`='".$_REQUEST['pass']."' , `name`='".$_REQUEST['name']."' , `lastname`='".$_REQUEST['lastname']."' , `phone`='".$_REQUEST['phone']."' , `state`='".$_REQUEST['state']."' , `details`='".$_REQUEST['details']."'  WHERE `id`='".$_REQUEST['id']."' ");
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
  }

if(isset($result1)){
?>
<script language="javascript">alert('successfuly updated');</script>
<?php
print(redirect('editteacher.php'));
}
  mysql_close();

?>

<?php
//for deleting Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
  if(isset($_POST['delete']) && $_POST['delete'] == 'delete user')
  {
$sql1=" DELETE FROM `".$tbl_name."` WHERE `username`='789' ";

$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

if(isset($result1)){
?>
<script language="javascript">alert('successfuly deleted');</script>
<?php

print(redirect('editteacher.php'));
  }
}
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: user permission on db?

Comment: Errors? Have you checked you actually have permissions for DELETE?

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Try connecting directly to the DB with your username and giving it a drop command. If you cannot drop it then you have a user permission problem.

Comment: in phpmyadmin i can delete rows is it different permisson?

Comment: Please rewrite this without `mysql_*` statements. ANYTHING could be sent as a request (`$_REQUEST['user']`) and could delete ANYTHING from your DB.

Comment: I updated the code to the code above but It still can not delete

Comment: `username = 789` matches 0 rows (doesn't exist)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
```

by

```
$result1=mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
```

That will show you any errors with the code.

Overall I would recommend improving your code:

```
$html = "";
$redirectTo = "";

// for updating Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit'] == 'update')
{
  $q = " UPDATE `".$tbl_name."` SET  `username`='".$_REQUEST['user']."' , `password`='".$_REQUEST['pass']."' , `name`='".$_REQUEST['name']."' , `lastname`='".$_REQUEST['lastname']."' , `phone`='".$_REQUEST['phone']."' , `state`='".$_REQUEST['state']."' , `details`='".$_REQUEST['details']."'  WHERE `id`='".$_REQUEST['id']."' ";
  $sql1 = mysql_query($q);
  $result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());

  if($result1){
    $html = "<script language=\"javascript\">alert(\"successfuly updated\");</script>";
    $redirectTo = "editteacher.php";
    //not sure what you are trying to do here?
    //print(redirect('editteacher.php'));
  }
}
//for deleting Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
elseif(isset($_POST['delete']) && $_POST['delete'] == 'delete user')
{
  $q = " DELETE FROM `".$tbl_name."` WHERE `username`='".$_REQUEST['user']."' ";
  $sql1=mysql_query($q);
  $result1=mysql_query($sql1);

  if($result1){
    $html = "<script language=\"javascript\">alert(\"successfuly deleted\");</script>";
    $redirectTo = "editteacher.php";
    //not sure what you are trying to do here?
    // print(redirect('editteacher.php'));
  }
}

echo $html;
if($redirectTo){
  print(redirect($redirectTo));
}
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Tnx I've done what you said and the error is "no data base selected" what should I do ?

Comment: That is because you close the connection. Try the code I have just added here now

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the double queries

   change  `$sql1=mysql_query(" UPDATE` ".$tbl_name." `to`$sql1=" UPDATE `".$tbl_name." because you have double query.

Comment: actually on the top my code there is a function for this line

Comment: yes, but if you have a function redirect($file){..} why you print it and not just run it. Does this work?